# ColdFusion 9 Error after Restart "The Cron service is not available."

Tags: windows-server-2008, coldfusion

What does this error mean?
And how can I fix it?

Comment: Q: What does this error mean? A: It means the Cron service is not available. Q: And how can I fix it? A: Make the Cron service available. - If you need a more detailed answer please provide a more detailed question.

Comment: Please review [this meta question on asking good questions](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault). joeqwerty's comment above is about the best we can do for you without more detail...

Comment: Don't abuse the edit system to get around your question ban. See [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) for more info on your ban, why it may be in place, and what you might do to get it removed.

Comment: It is an easy to understand question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not mention what version of ColdFusion you are on or what OS version you are running.  That might help.

I was able to find this post about that error - [ACF8 - THE CRON SERVICE IS NOT AVAILABLE.](http://blog.maestropublishing.com/acf8-the-cron-service-is-not-available)

Basically it states:

> This happens because the neo-cron.xml file in /WEB-INF/cfusion/lib has been corrupted. You can replace it with the neo-cron.bk file however in my case that file is always corrupted as well.

And they go on to supply the text for a new file if needed.  Maybe that will help you.